# UINavigationView can not pop, Only navigation pop animation, UIViewController not changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I use the custom `UINavigationController` as a rootViewController. The `UINavigationController's` first viewController is a `UITabBarController`. Each `UITabBarController` is a custom `UINavigationConller`.When the `tabBarController` is shown, I hide the `rootViewController's` `navigationBar`.

> Init the `UITabbarController`

```
+(RDVTabBarController *)tabBarControllertWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    UIViewController *goodsHomeController = [[ESGoodsHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *goodsHomeNavi = [[ESNavigationController alloc]
                                               initWithRootViewController:goodsHomeController];
    ........     
    ESTabBarController *tabBarController = [[ESTabBarController alloc] init]; //对status bar 能定制
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:@[goodsHomeNavi,categoryNavi,shoppingCarNavi,userCenterNavi]];
    return tabBarController;

}
```

> Set it to a `navigationController`

```
self.tabController = [UIHelper tabBarControllertWithIndex:0];
self.tableController.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *tabBarNavigation = [UIHelper navigationControllerViewController:self.tableController];
tabBarNavigation.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarNavigation;
```

> In the baseViewController ,I customise the back item in the navigationBar

```
- (void)setCustomNavigationBackButton
{
    UIImage *backBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_back"];
    UIImage *backDownBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_back_down"];
    backBtn = [backBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    backDownBtn = [backDownBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backBtn;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backBtn;
}
```

> In some cases, I change the `viewControllers` of a `navigationController` when I push a `viewController` after the push animation is finished. I use a navigationController+block

```
- (void)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated onCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:completion];
    [self popToViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    [CATransaction commit];

}
```

After finished the block is executed

```
 [UIHelper viewController:self pushViewController:orderDetail completion:^{

        NSMutableArray *afterController = [NSMutableArray array]; //将本页面删除

        NSArray *viewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
        [viewController enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIViewController *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            if (![obj isKindOfClass:[ESPurchaseViewController class]]) {
                [afterController addObject:obj];
            }

        }];

        self.navigationController.viewControllers = afterController;

    }];
```

In some push, when I come from the `UITabBarController` push to a `secondViewController`, I hide `navigationBar` and show the root `navigationBar`.

```
+(void)tabController:(UIViewController *)tabController pushSubController:(UIViewController *)subViewController
{
    [tabController.rdv_tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:subViewController animated:YES];
    tabController.rdv_tabBarController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;
}
```

I can not find the reason why the navigation can not pop. That does not always happen. 
Any wrong basic knowledge of iOS about the `UINavigationContller`,`UITabBarController`,`UIViewController` for me to know?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if i think your need is First MainNavigationViewController then tabbar Controller with it and each tab bar's view controller is also having its own nvaigation controller then it will work fine..

```
listViewController = [[CBListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    bookmarkController = [[CBBookmarksViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    settingsController = [[CBActivityViewController alloc] init ];
    searchController = [[CBSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CBSearchViewController" bundle:nil];
    nearbyController = [[CBViewOnMapViewController alloc] init ];
   UINavigationController *bNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bookmarkController];
    self.navigationControllerForBookmark = bNavigationController;

    UITabBarItem *tab2=[[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    tab2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab2.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark_active.png"]  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
    navigationControllerForBookmark.tabBarItem = tab2;


    UINavigationController *cNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsController];
    self.navigationControllerForSettings = cNavigationController;

    UITabBarItem *tab3=[[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    tab3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"activites.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab3.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"activites_active.png"]  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab3.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
    navigationControllerForSettings.tabBarItem = tab3;


    UINavigationController *dNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchController];
    self.navigationControllerForSearch = dNavigationController;

    UITabBarItem *tab4=[[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    tab4.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab4.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search_active.png"]  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.navigationController.tabBarItem = tab4;
    tab4.imageInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
    navigationControllerForSearch.tabBarItem=tab4;

    UINavigationController *eNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nearbyController];
    self.navigationControllerForNearby = eNavigationController;

    UITabBarItem *tab5=[[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    tab5.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nearby.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab5.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nearby_active.png"]  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.navigationController.tabBarItem = tab5;
    tab5.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
    navigationControllerForNearby.tabBarItem = tab5;

    [navigationControllerForNearby.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"headerBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:listViewController];
    self.navigationController = aNavigationController;


    UITabBarItem *tab1=[[UITabBarItem alloc]init];
    tab1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"review.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"review_active.png"]  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
    navigationController.tabBarItem = tab1;


    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:GRAY_COLOR];


    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];


    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, navigationControllerForNearby, navigationControllerForSearch, navigationControllerForBookmark, navigationControllerForSettings, nil];

 self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

check if this solves your problem sir.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use the RDVTabBarControllerthe replace the system's UITabBarController. the tabbarcontroller has a navigationcontroller and  each tab bar's view controller is also having its own nvaigation controller.

Comment: are you getting me sir

Comment: Sorry for replay you later. My method is the same as you told me. and It seem that It not solves the problem.